# Iterate through the files in a given folder in Enterprise Connect with Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, opentext

I want to iterate through the files in a given folder in Enterprise Connect to check, if file exists, delete or add files.

I am able to access the folders, but can't iterate through the items:

```
Sub IterateEnterpriseConnect()
Dim FP As MAPIFolder
Dim folder As MAPIFolder


Set FP = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Enterprise Connect").Folders("FolderName1").Folders("FolderName2").Folders("FolderName3").Folders("FolderName4").Folders("FolderName5")
MsgBox FP.Name
For Each Elem In FP.Items
        MsgBox Elem.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

MsgBox. FP.Name returns the expected Name of the selected folder, but while there a numerous pdf-files in the folder FP.Items seems to be empty.

Any idea how i can access or iterate the items in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook folder does not store files, it stores messages. Even if you have what looks like a file (Outlook opens it when you double click on a message), the folder contains messages with the message class of `IPM.Document.<Attachment type>`, e.g. `"IPM.Document.Acrobat.Document.DC"` for PDF files. Take a look at a message with [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMessage and/or Item buttons.

Messages like that are represented by the [DocumentItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.documentitem) object in the Outlook Object Model. Just like regular messages ([MailItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem) object), they expose `Subject` property and the `Attachments` collection.

```
Dim Attach as Attachment
...
For Each Elem In FP.Items
  MsgBox Elem.Subject
  For Each Attach in Elem.Attachments
    MsgBox Attach.FileName
  Next
Next
```